# Non Qt GUI application using Qt GUI DLL library

Tags: dll

We want to purchase QT License – Desktop – Multi OS. We have started to develop with the open SDK and came across a very crucial problem.

One of our components is Qt DLL which expose GUI dialogs. If we call it from other Qt applications, or even none Qt console application everything is fine and the DLL is able to show its dialogs. But, when we try to load dialogs from another none-Qt GUI application, Java application for instance, the application is not able to continue, no dialog is showed and we get the following error at the command line window we have run the application from: “QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread”.

We are testing it on Linux Ubuntu. All we need is to be able to show dialogs from Qt DLL being loaded by none-Qt GUI application